# Discord Js Lost on how to make a voice mute command

Tags: javascript, discord

I was trying to find many threads about making a command that specifically mutes one single person that I tag in chat but I can't seem to find any help on it. I am pretty new to discord / node js and could use some help.

[Mute everyone in a voice channel with a Discord Bot with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081354/mute-everyone-in-a-voice-channel-with-a-discord-bot-with-discord-js)

I have tried trying to find out if I can make sense of this and replace everyone with one person but I can't seem to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[setMute](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setMute) is now a method of `member.voice`.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('/mute')) {
        if (!message.mentions.members.first()) return
        message.mentions.members.first().voice.setMute(true)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out and added a bunch of stuff to it